# Code generators or ORMs?

Tags: orm, code-generation, data-access-layer

What do you suggest for Data Access layer? Using ORMs like Entity Framework and Hibernate OR Code Generators like Subsonic, .netTiers, T4, etc.?

Answer (score 8):

For me, this is a no-brainer, you *generate* the code.

I'm going to go slightly off topic here because there's a bigger underlying fallacy at play. The fallacy is that these ORM frameworks *solve* the object/relational impedence mismatch. This claim is a barefaced lie.

I find the best way to resolve the object/relational impedance mismatch is to either use OOP exclusively and use an object database or use the idioms of the relational database exclusively and ignore OOP.

The abstraction "everything is a table" is to me, much more powerful than the abstraction "everything is a class." It takes less code, less intellectual effort and leads to *faster* code when you code to the database rather than to an object model.

To me this seems obvious. If your application is data driven then surely your code should be data driven too? Yet to say this is hugely controversial.

The central problem here is that OOP becomes a really leaky abstraction when used in conjunction with a database. Code that look perfectly sensible when written to the idioms of OOP looks completely insane when you see the traffic that code generates at the database. When that messiness becomes a performance problem, OOP is the first casualty.

There is really no way to resolve this. Databases work with *sets* of data. OOP focus on *instances* of classes. Trying to marry the two is always going to end in divorce.

So to answer your question, I believe you should generate your classes and try and make them map the underlying database structure as closely as possible.

Comment: What about using ORMs with the active record pattern? Your object model is based off of tables/records, but you get the dynamic query/lazy loading, and less code (less to test) benefits of ORM.

Comment: You don't need an ORM to interface with your database. You can use a tool that provides source code generation AND provides easy access to the relational data model of your RDBMS. http://jooq.sourceforge.net is such a tool that you might like, actually

Comment: @Daniel: then you don't program OO. Active Record is "everything is a table".

Comment: @Stephan, I'm not sure I'm following you. Are you saying an app can't be OO if the active record pattern is used? If so, I think a lot of rails developers will disagree. ;)

Comment: I have no idea what he thinks. However I know that active record is an ORM pattern that can be used when your object model maps 1:1 to database tables. I don't see how that precludes your app from being OO. The OOness of an app is mostly orthogonal to the underlying persistence structure in my experience. Here is Fowler's definition: "An object that wraps a row in a database table or view, encapsulates the database access, and adds domain logic on that data." All that being said, I've often seen apps that use active record that are more "object based" than "OO" due to the programmer.

Comment: My experience has been the opposite, and I have to agree with Simon. But of course I solved it by using Gemstone. http://blip.tv/file/568689 and a year later http://vimeo.com/1147409

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps controversially, I've always felt that using code generators for the ADO.NET plumbing is fundamentally solving the wrong problem.

At some point, hopefully not too long after learning about Connection Strings, SqlCommands, DataAdapters, and all that, we notice that:

1. Such code is ugly
2. It is very boring to write
3. It's very easy to miss something if you're doing it by hand
4. It has to be repeated every time you want to access the database

So, the problem to solve is "how to do the same thing lots of times fast"?

I say no.

Using code generators to make this process quick still means that you have a ton of code, all the same, all over your business classes (or your data access layer, if you separate that from your business logic).

And then, if you want to do something generically (like track stored procedure usage, for instance), you end up having to customise your code generator if it doesn't already have the feature you want.  And even if it does, you still have to regenerate everything all the time.

I like to do things once, not many times, no matter how fast I can do them.

So I rolled my own Data Access class that knows how to add parameters, set up and close connections, manage transactions, and other cool stuff.  It only had to be written once, and calling its methods from a Business object that needs some database stuff done consists of one line of code.

When I needed to make the application support multithreaded database accesses, it required a change to the Data Access class only, and all the business classes just do what they already did.

Comment: And if you write it yourself, you don't end up refactoring everything next time the annual "paradigm 20xx" comes around obsoleting last year's model.

Answer (score 1):

There is no right answer it all depends on your project. As Simon points out if your application is all data driven, then it might make sense depending on the size and complexity of the domain to use non oop paradigm. I had a lot of success building a system using a Transaction Script pattern, which passed XML Messages around the system.

However this system started to break down after five or six years as the application grew in size and complexity (5 or 6 webs, several web services, tons of COM+ components, legacy and .net code, 8+ databases with 800+ tables 4,000+ procedures). No one knew what anything was, and duplication was running rampant.

There are other ways to alleviate the maintance then OOP; however, if you have a very complex domain then hainvg a rich domain model is ideal IMHO, as it allows for the business rules to be expressed in nice encapsulated components.

To answer your question, avoid code generators if you can. Code generators are a recipe for disaster, but if you do go with code generation do not modify the generated code. Also be sure to have a good process in place that is easy for developers to get the new generated code.

I recommend using either the following: ORM or hand roll a lightweight DAL. I am currently transitioning a project over to nHibernate off my hand rolled DAL and am having a lot of success; however, I like having the option of using either option. Further if you properly seperate your concerns (Data Access from Business Layer from Presentation) you can have a single service layer that might talk to a Dao (Data Access Object) that for one object is an ORM but for another is hand rolled). I like this flexibility as it allows to apply the best tool to the job.

I like nHibernate over a hand rolled DAL because while my DAL does abstract away most of the ADO.Net code you still have to write the code that takes a data reader to an object or an object and creates the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I've always preferred to go the code generator route, especially in C# where you can make use of extended classes to add functionality to the basic data objects.

Answer (score 0):

Hate to say this, but it depends. If you find an ORM tool that fits your needs go for it. We wrote our own system in small steps while developing the application. We are using C++ and there are not that many tools out there anyway. Ours ended up being a XML description of the database, from that the SQL generation script and the basic object layer and metadata were generated.

Do your homework and evaluate theses tools and you will find a good fit for your needs.